# CallKit with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I have developed an app using the `CoreTelephony` framework to detect changes in the phone status that works beautifully.  The generic form of the Swift code (leveraged from another `StackOverflow` answer) is:

```
import CoreTelephony

class SomeClass: UIViewController {

    private var callCenter = CTCallCenter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       callCenter.callEventHandler = { (call:CTCall!) in

           switch call.callState {
               case CTCallStateConnected:
                    println("CTCallStateConnected")
                   self.callConnected()
               case CTCallStateDisconnected:
                   println("CTCallStateDisconnected")
                   self.callDisconnected()
               default:
               //Not concerned with CTCallStateDialing or CTCallStateIncoming
                   break
           }
       }
   }

   func callConnected(){
       // Do something when call connects
   }

   func callDisconnected() {
       // Do something when call disconnects
   }
}
```

As the `CoreTelephony` framework has been largely deprecated and been replaced by the `CallKit` framework, I would like to replace this code with the equivalent `CallKit` framework Swift code.  I have tried to use my limited knowledge to do this, but I not been successful.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific about what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

1. `let c = CXCallController()`
2. `let o = c.callObserver`
3. `o.setDelegate(delegateThatIWillCreate, queue: DispatchQueue(label:"dispatchQueue for delegate"))`
4. implement the delegate.
5. win!

Comment: Joe - Thanks for our response.  I have tried to take your response and apply it, with no luck.  I am a Swift (and object oriented programming) newbie and I am still trying to work out "delegates", especially the code format.  Any chance that you could expand the code for implementing the delegate that would give the equivalent functionality to my current code.  Thanks in advance.